# Why this code doesn't display all chars in the file ? I tried also getc() and fscanf(); aslo doesn't not worked. look at the screen shot?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>



int main()
{
    char str[1];
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("dataloger.txt", "rb");    
    while(fread(&str[0], sizeof(str),  1, file) ==1){
        if(str[0] =='\n'){
            str[0] = '#';
        } 
        printf("%s", str);     
    }
    fclose(file);

/************************************************
    int c; 
    if (file) {
        while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF){
            if(c =='\n') {
                c = '#';
            }
            printf("%c", c);
        }     

        fclose(file);
    }
```

could someone explain why I didn't see normal output not just #?
As I faced the problem only after I try to replace the char'\n' by another char and print it.
Look at the screen shot added[image]

Comment: `str` is not a nul terminated string, it is a single character. You can't print it with `%s`.

Comment: Replace `printf("%s", str)` with `printf("%c", str[0])` or `putchar(str[0])`

Comment: @M.NejatAydin I tried to replace but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

I copied in your code minus the commented out bits and did some testing.  Following is a version of your code with some tweaks.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char str;           /* In reality, "str" is a character - a string normally would be at least two characters long with a NULL terminator */
    FILE *fp;           /* Don't like to name variables with possibly reserved words */

    fp = fopen("dataloger.txt", "rb");

    if (fp == NULL)     /* Just to make the program more robust */
    {
        printf("Could not find the file\n");
        return -1;
    }

    while(fread(&str, sizeof(str), 1, fp) ==1)
    {
        if(str =='\n')
        {
            str = '#';
        }
        printf("%c", str);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    printf("\n");       /* Just to be neat */

    return 0;

}
```

Following are some points to note.

- First, since the program is supposed to read a character at a time from the text file, it seemed more clear to utilize a character variable in lieu of a character array that had a length of "1".  Technically both work, but that would come across a bit clearer to anyone analyzing the program.
- It's usually a good idea to shy away from naming variables that might have reserved meaning in a program language.  Although "file" and "FILE" are different names, it can add to confusion if anyone is analyzing this code.
- Also, when working with files, it is often a good idea to check to make sure there were no issues with opening the file; therefore, a check to see if the file pointer is not NULL is beneficial - this might be at the core of your issue depending upon where the text file is in relation to the compiled program.

Testing out this tweaked code, a simple two-line text file was set up with the following test data.

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.
```

Executing the code resulted in the following output at the terminal (the program was compiled with a name of "ReadFile").

```
@Dev:~/C_Programs/Console/ReadFile/bin/Release$ ./ReadFile 
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.#Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.#
```

Give those tweaks a try to see if it meets the spirit of your project.